# How to avoid writing a .bat file, by executing a .cs file as a script?

Tags: .net, batch-file, dos

I'd like to write a simple batch file to copy a few files around.

However, I'm tired of batch files as they are so limiting, and I'd like to just write a simple .cs file which I can execute as a script, directly from the command line.

How can I run a ".cs" file from the command line, and have it run an a script?

Comment: `Write-Output "<3 PowerShell"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.csscript.net/, if you install it you can run simple .cs files just like DOS batch files (i.e. no need to compile them into a project).

Answer (score 5):

You can't unless you compile it. However, [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa973757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a similar syntax to C# and is very powerful.

Comment: *blinks* you have odd ideas of similarity.

Comment: I know C# like the back of my hand. Why learn PowerShell if I can just rename my .cs file to .csx and it will execute just like a powershell script (see my answer below)?

Comment: @Joey dots, brackets and such ;)

Answer (score 4):

You would need to compile it into an executable file, and then run this executable.

Maybe you could write a batch file to achieve this?

---

On a more serious note, do take a look at Powershell as an alternative as mentioned by scottm's answer (which I've +1ed accordingly).

Comment: Compiling it into an executable is a bit of an overkill for a .cs file with a few lines, DOS batch files are so limiting, and PowerShell requires learning a whole new language (I already know C# quite well).

Comment: .NET is not an interpreted platform when writing in high level languages like C#. They need to be compiled into IL to run on the CLR. Thus compilation is not "overkill" it is a necessary step. And it needs to be compiled into something that can be run, hence executable. Your find of Microsoft Roslyn is interesting...

Comment: @David M I've just written 30k lines of C#, and when I had to write a tiny DOS batch file, it was so limiting that I set my system up to run .csx files from the command line, just like a DOS batch file.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Roslyn](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27746) allows you to execute a C# file from the command line, just like batch files, PowerShell, Python, etc.

**Step 1:** Install Roslyn, create a new console app, then use the following line to execute a script:

```
scriptEngine.ExecuteFile("DemoClass.cs");
```

or

```
scriptEngine.ExecuteFile("DemoScript.csx");
```

**Step 2:** Associate ".csx" files with your compiled console app, and they will execute just as if they had been compiled into a visual studio project.

Now I never have to write a DOS batch file in my life, again.

**Update**

- Step 1, above was greatly simplified. For full instructions, see http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx
- In order to pass command line arguments to the program, you will need sessions, as described at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at how to compile programs at the command prompt. Using this technique, you could feed in your .cs file, compile the .exe, then run the .exe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172492%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

However, this seems like it would be a bit cumbersome. What's wrong with just firing up Visual Studio and typing out the code really quick in a command line project?

Comment: I suppose you could always write a batch script to automate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/
Tho I'm not entirely sure it's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $Source = (gc csharpfilename.cs|Out-String)
    #compile Csharp
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp

    #Call you function like this
    [namespaceName.className]::functionName("Parameters/Arguments")
```